# How to search inside a list of files for multiple values exisiting on the same line?

Tags: command-line, grep

I am trying to do a search in one directory containing a large number of html files, to find those files that contain the exact values on the same line. This should work:

```
grep -iwc 'word1' -sl | xargs grep -iwc 'word2' -s
```

But that only works on one file at a time. I tried something like this:

```
find . -iname '*html' | xargs grep -iwc 'word1' -sl | xargs grep -iwc 'word2' -s
```

But that seems to display files containing any of the two values, so even those that are not on the same line.

The output should only be the file names and the number of occurrences like:

```
file.html:2
```

If it possible to group those 2 greps? Or another way to do this search?

Comment: Are you matching specific search terms or are you just looking for every corresponding matching line?

Comment: I am looking for all files that match the same word1 and word2 (or string2) which are located on the same line, and output that like file.html:x where x is the number of occurrences. It seems the answer by phs does the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extended regex may help.  Something like this perhaps?

```
find . -iname '*html' | xargs egrep -iwl '(word1.*word2|word2.*word1)'
```

Since you only have two words you're looking for, it's not too hard to list off all the ways to order them.

Comment: This seems to work :) If using a word and a string, that would work too, right? Such as word1 and 'this string of words' on the same line, but without the quotes (since with quotes it returns nothing).

Comment: Yes, so long as it can be formed as a regex.  Letters and spaces can without special treatment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You won't believe how long i have been search for this. Can this also be extended to search for word1 AND (word2 OR word3)?

Comment: The `|` above means "OR".  So perhaps `word1.*(word2|word3)`.  If you have the time, reading up on "regular expressions" should help.